# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory + JDBC Driver class not found

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, gwt

i have this project where i'm using hibernate, maven,gwt ,JPA, Tomcat, and spring,mysql. Anyway i have been trying to solve this error with no success.
I have already configured my mysql connector "mysql-connector-java"
this is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: projetA] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at com.pac.projetA.shared.Dto.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:883)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:84)
    ... 12 more
    enter code here
```

Comment: How did you configure the jar?

Comment: I added the jar in the classpath i + I added the dependency in the pom.xml

Comment: I suggest you don't do both.

Comment: I tried but it does not work :(

Comment: Clearly your classpath is not set correctly. Play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I do remember you were using maven. Make sure you clean and build your project and restart your server to pick up the changes to your classpath if you do have the following entry in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

This dude has some good tutorials btw

This is one is how to use hibernate, maven and mysql

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/